# Clang AST Visitor returns wrong data type when visiting variable declarations

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang

Hello I have implemented an AST visitor using clang. It can correctly detect whenever a variable is declared, but sometimes it returns the wrong type for the variable. For example if a variable is declared as size_t or char32_t or even george it returns its type as int. 
My code is here:

```
virtual bool VisitVarDecl(VarDecl *var) 
{
    numVariables++;
    string varName = var->getQualifiedNameAsString();
    string varType = var->getType().getAsString();
    cout << "VisitVarDecl: " << varName << " of type " << varType << "\n";        
    APIs << varType << ", ";
    return true;
}
```

Anyone knows why?
I would like my code to identify any variable declaration but even with an imaginary type such as `test i; george x;`
Thank you

Comment: If I include the corresponding header files it returns everything correct. I am expecting to get the correct variable type just by syntax, as a human will understand that declaring horse x will be a variable x of type horse without having any knowledge about the horse type.